# UIAlertController not working Xibs?

Tags: objective-c, xib, uialertcontroller

In my project i am using xib's in that i want to show UIAlertController and perform some actions.but i am getting error.

Here is my code.

[image]

What is the mistake in my code.

Comment: What is `self`? What `EditProfile` inherits from?

Comment: @Larme. interface EditProfile : UIView

Comment: Well, `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is a `UIViewController` method, not a `UIView` one.

Comment: @Larme. for what about UIView?

Comment: `self` is a `UIView`. It doesn't know the method `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. That's normal, it's a `UIViewController` object job to do so.

Comment: @Larme. i am creating UIAlertController in xibs and loading that xibs in UIViewController.how can i show the alertcontroller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107953/discussion-between-user558-and-larme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when add xibView in UIVieController assign self in ParentViewController.

i.e

```
_xibView *objxibView = [[xibView alloc]init];

objxibView.parentViewController = self;
```

in Xib's xibView.h file create 1 property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *parentViewController;
```

and in xibView.m File  use below code
for UIAlertController in xib

```
{
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                 message:nil 
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *actionOK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:actionOK];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: in my xib .h file creating property like this @property (retain, nonatomic) TestingViewController *testingViewController; getting error. here TestingViewController is a my xibs loading view

Comment: not TestingViewController object .. create UIViewController Object . see above code

Comment: i also tried that one also ,but it is not showing alert.

Comment: Debug Code And check what object get in "self.parentViewController" at presentViewController. in self.parentViewController getting parent VC Object?

Comment: i am getting like this, po benView.parentViewController
<TestingViewController: 0x7969fbe0>